# Indefinite Integral of a Probability Density Function

Tags: integration, density-function

I'm tying myself in knots on something seemingly simple, and I'm not sure if I'm just missing something obvious. However...

Why is that:

$\int f(x) dx = F_x(x) - 1$

where does the constant $-1$ come from exactly?

By definition:

$\int_{-\infty}^{x} f(x) dx = F_x(x)$

But it is lost on me how the indefinite integral is how it is?

Thanks to anyone that can shed some light.

Comment: In what context did you see the equation $\int f(x) dx = F_X(x) - 1$?

Comment: I saw it in relation to a proof that the limited expected value of a random variable is equal to $\int (1-F_X(x)) dx$ with the upper limit of integration equal to the censoring point. That's my main goal, but it's just this little snag that I cannot get around..

Comment: Recall how integration by parts works; if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are functions, then
$$
\int f(x)\,g(x)\,dx=f(x)G(x)-\int f'(x)\,G(x)\,dx,
$$
where $G(x)$ is any antiderivative of $g$, that is, any function for which $G'(x)=g(x)$. This means that $G(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x g(x)\,dx+C$, and you can choose whatever constant you want. The author of the proof you were reading chose the constant $C=-1$, because it is most convenient.

Comment: I'm sorry, but in the politest way possible - how does that help derive the indefinite integral I am after? The definition of the CDF (your G(x)) is with C = 0

Comment: The correct statement is $\int_\infty^xf(x')dx'=F(x)-1$.

Answer (score 1):

The proof you are reading (I assume) starts by trying to evaluate
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\,f(x)\,dx
$$
using integration by parts. In order to do this, we need to choose two functions $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ such that
$$
x\, f(x)\,dx=u\,dv=u(x)\,v'(x)\,dx
$$
The split which is most convenient for this problem is
$$
u(x)=x,\qquad v'(x)=f(x)
$$
Since $v'(x)=f(x)$, integrating both sides implies $$v(x)=\int f(x)\,dx +C$$
Furthermore, we know that $F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(x)$, so $F_X(x)$ is *an* antiderivative of $f$. Plugging this into the above, we get
$$
v(x)=F_X(x)+C
$$
However, *you can choose $C$ to be whatever you want*. The point is, the author of the proof chose $C=-1$, because it happened to be the most convenient choice for completing the proof.

---

Note that the equation
$$
\int f(x)\,dx =F_X(x)-1
$$
you wrote is not true! The indefinite integration symbol $\int f(x)\,dx$ refers to the entire suite of functions whose derivative is equal to $f$. What you can say is that $F_X(x)-1$ is **an** antiderivative of $f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks Mike for the reply. I do understand the above. I guess I could rephrase my question slightly and ask, in the relationship between PDFs and CDFs, is it always the case that C is chosen to be -1? Does it have to be? This is certainly the case for a few examples I've looked at. It also seems to be true based on the proof I am looking at (see bottom of the third page, here: https://probability.oer.math.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/2187/2020/08/ch16E.pdf)

Comment: @Delvesy The only time I have seen the choice of $C=-1$ is in the proof of $E[X]=\int_0^\infty (1-F_X(x))\,dx$. It is a necessary choice in that context, or else the new integral you get does not converge. At the bottom of the third page, they could have chosen $C=0$.